# Broadcast é executado uma vez mas o evento é chamado 2 vezes

Tags: angularjs

Tenho o seguinte "broadcast" dentro de uma "directive":

```
console.log('a emitir...');
$rootScope.$broadcast('olamundo', params);
```

No meu "controller" tenho o seguinte código:

```
$scope.$on('olamundo', function (event, args) {
    console.log('a escutar...');
    //aqui vai o código
});
```

O meu evento "olamundo" está sendo executado 2 vezes, aparece 2 vezes a frase "a escutar..." na consola (devido ao "console.log" no código acima).
Na "directive" onde o "broadcast" é emitido, a frase 'a emitir...' aparece penas uma vez.
Não há outro "broadcast" com esse mesmo nome, porque o evento 'olamundo' está sendo executado 2 vezes?

Comment: Seria possível você fazer um exemplo funcional no [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)? Sem ver o resto do código não dá pra ter certeza do que está causando o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto pode ser um indicativo que você possui, na verdade, duas instâncias do seu *controller*.

Isso pode ocorrer caso você esteja mencionando o controller como parte da configuração do `ui-router` (ou `$stateProvider`, caso você esteja utilizando `ui-router`) E também no documento HTML.

Se este for o caso, remova um dos dois (a configuração do `ng-router`/`ui-router` ou a menção no HTML.)

Comment: Estou a usar o "angular-ui-router", porém estou a declarar o controller somente no $stateProvider. Há alguma maneira mais fácil de descobrir se estou a declarar 2 vezes? Ou o jeito é ver o HTML e procurar?

Comment: Reparei que isso acontece em qualquer controller onde tenho o "$scope.$on('olamundo'...", ou seja, para isso teria que cometer esse erro em tudo, mas não é o caso. Poderá ser outro motivo?

Comment: O problema foi resolvido, tinha 2 instâncias do mesmo controlador, porém não no HTML e sim no "$stateProvider". Estava utilizando o mesmo controlador para a rota "app" e para a rota "app.dashboard". A rota "app" é abstrata mas declaro uma view com o mesmo controlador. Já corrigir o problema e não volto a utilizar o mesmo controlador, isso só trouxe problemas. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes desculpe a demora em lhe responder, mas fico feliz que você tenha achado a solução.